# Differences in OllyDbg and IDA PRO for MOVSX EDX, BYTE PTR [ESP+ECX+8] command

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida, ollydbg

While disassembling the same program using OllyDbg and IDA PRO I have one line of code disassembled in different ways.

OllyDBG:

```
    MOVSX EDX,BYTE PTR [ESP+ECX+8]
```

IDA:

```
    MOVSX EDX, [ESP+ECX+68h+String]
```

Can someone explain what does IDA PRO mean here? I am frustrated by 68h+String part here. Can I assume that 68h+String always means BYTE PTR?

Comment: I don't think so. What do the raw bytes look like, and what is `String` according to IDA pro?

Comment: @sircodesalot it's a `movsx` so yes, it can be a `byte ptr`.

Comment: Algorithm is:

Prerequisites: there is a text string.


Step 1: Move first character of string into EDX

Step 2: Do smth with it

Step 3: Move to next character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ida should have declared `STRING to be a LOCAL variable` with a value of -60h look at 
the start of function / procedure

( 68 + STRING ) == ( 68 + (- 60 ) ) == (68-60) == 8 
it is same as what ollydbg shows .

IDA's disassembly syntax tends  to be confusing

as an example ollydbg will show

```
00405712     8B4424 30       MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+30]
```

while ida would show

```
text:00405712                 mov     eax, [esp+1Ch+arg_4]
```

because at the start of function ida has defined arg_4 as

```
.text:004056E0 arg_4           = dword ptr  14h
```

that is

```
14h + 1ch == 30h
```

if you do not prefer ida syntax but would like to see a straight  [esp+30]

you can run this script

```
shift +f2 paste and press ok
```

beware all ida idc functions are too slow for any mass operations 
instead of MaxEA() curtail it to some smaller block for a faster result in the snippet below

```
auto i;

for (  i = MinEA() ; i < MaxEA() ; i = NextHead(i, MaxEA()) )
{
    OpHex(i,-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IDA tries to set this command in relation to a local variable. `[ESP+ECX+8]` points to the same address as `[ESP+ECX+68h+String]`. You can read IDA's output as `[ESP+ECX+8+String+60h]`.I'm confused too that IDA makes no difference between `BYTE PTR` and `WORD PTR`, both result in different commands.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a similar IDA issue. IDA list this instruction correct as:

`inc     byte ptr ds:900h`

but when you put a label on the offset, it does

`inc     ds:byte_900`

Effectively the ptr and byte reference is gone by naming an offset.. :shrug: